# How can I change the type of Object.fromEntries?

Tags: typescript

I want to change the type of the object created fromEntries to be of the Program interface:

```js
interface exerciseCategory {
  [exerciseCategories: string]: string[];
}

interface muscleGroup {
  [muscleGroups: string]: exerciseCategory;
}

export default interface Program {
  [days: string]: muscleGroup;
}

const program: Program = {
  "Day 1": {
    Chest: {
      warmUp: ["parallel bar dips"],
      main: ["Bench Press", "Inclined Bench press", "Decline Bench press"],
      secondary: ["Dumbbell Flys", "Cable Crossover Flys", "Pec-deck Fly"],
    },
    Biceps: {
      Lola: ["Barbell Curl", "Preacher Curl"],
      bobo: ["Hammer Curls", "Cable Curl", "Dumbbell Curl"],
    },
  },
  "Day 2": {
    Shoulders: {
      coso: ["parallel bar dips"],
      coque: ["Bench Press", "Inclined Bench press", "Decline Bench press"],
      sdary: ["Dumbbell Flys", "Cable Crossover Flys", "Pec-deck Fly"],
    },
    Abs: {
      main: ["Crunch", "Leg raises"],
    },
  },
  "Day 3": {
    Back: {
      warmUp: ["parallel bar dips"],
      main: ["Bench Press", "Inclined Bench press", "Decline Bench press"],
      secondary: ["Dumbbell Flys", "Cable Crossover Flys", "Pec-deck Fly"],
    },
    Triceps: {
      main: ["Barbell Curl", "Preacher Curl"],
      secondary: ["Hammer Curls", "Cable Curl", "Dumbbell Curl"],
    },
  },
};



const days: Array<[string, object]> = Object.entries(program);

days[0][0] = 'New day name'

const newProgram:Program = Object.fromEntries(days)
```

However for const newProgram:Program = Object.fromEntries(days) I get :
Type '{ [k: string]: object; }' is not assignable to type 'Program'.
Index signatures are incompatible.
Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'muscleGroup'.
Index signature is missing in type '{}'

How can I make it work?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=56&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAggD2g4BnCBhOSAcwHsoBPZAbwChlkBtdTHfQiUqYCbALmWxguIIgF1+g4UQaiA3DQC+NGqEixEKALYBXbAgA2EAOJQS2gA7U6jHXsMmz5vgKGgx-ZlCy4CxMuXklGnRzMjBkABMIeG19cNVoeCRkAAVTIig4TSt6Bgi4cmdJN3FkWwNjUwtA5QQSEEFkc3TMzX40kgys5ABeHOQAIgARAuQARgH+Wnp6PAALHjAp6xnkAHc4KE0AVXN+BgHzTbh9Q31kACNNyOAnAdEAGhWZzThQfYGAIQgQBDnUqA8bADB6DACSv30oAgEWQ31+-2aQJBgyGEAM0LhPz+TUB2GBj2e9FwdRA+QoHyG2k0FwuEFOyAAYvpCiiBgQLoZkHhTPiSAA3aBMlnA0EDFLogC0UQQAGtheR7k9VgplTNPsAkE5lqt6AAZEj6OAfT6bOkMvDaKD6NlpCCIBZQblWm2E3WXEgXEgfAASWU0Qst1tFgw5XKDNrFVJp5vOEaVz1V1iT9GGowATJN+vQAMpzMz6KJQZzTXV1bDexiHY6nemXa4RW4EtWrOoAR20EBN2P+dvxbIhGJAMKxCNxyKj6Khw9HOKR-bduuw5PIlOptPp52ZrLFYZQPJIfMFTu3IfFUpl8u3CZVLeQAEELiWiWU3iAPjztAi2XqOMhMqwzaJmqKaoqMADMWalvQppyjquobFsuwfEcmS1ucVxOo2dyLqsrzvFW8I4n2Z6DtOI5EYieJnmiQ4oJR44LnexLovUK5rjGm4Kmee7cryFbHtxtoXuiV4sjeMygfQAAqXBas+7r4e+hFmlx8ZinaDqBi6EmrCSbGbKuVZ+poAZOhGPFwJy+46VG66xs61q6cgoFJgo8jKDQpKNPkhT8PeUCZOQAA8DDFCIoKegAVuiYCiAAfL0yAAPIXDFCBgAAdD8rg8AAFM0nStAAlB5vnYAwAAMohVaISUAOQAHIQGskSjCAWQQPVtT1I0w5rB0XRtINrRJal6VZTApiaAAouAXD5eVxXKEAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often in TypeScript a round-trip through `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()` will lose information about the relationships between particular keys and their value types, and you'd need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) somewhere to either preserve or re-establish such information.

In your case, though, `Program` doesn't have particular known keys; it has a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) so every possible string key has a potential value of type `muscleGroup`.  `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()` will therefore work just fine as-is, *unless you get in their way*.

For some reason, you annotated `days` as being of type `Array<[string, object]>`, widening the value types from `muscleGroup` to `object`.  This throws away information.  You'd be better off just letting the compiler *infer* the type of `days`:

```
const days = Object.entries(program);
//  [string, muscleGroup][]
```

And then everything will work as expected:

```
const newProgram: Program = Object.fromEntries(days); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAggD2g4BnCBhOSAcwHsoBPZAbwChlkBtdTHfQiUqYCbALmWxguIIgF1+g4UQaiA3DQC+NGqEixEKALYBXbAgA2EAOJQS2gA7U6jHXsMmz5vgKGgx-ZlCy4CxMuXklGnRzMjBkABMIeG19cNVoeCRkAAVTIig4TSt6Bgi4cmdJN3FkWwNjUwtA5QQSEEFkc3TMzX40kgys5ABeHOQAIgARAuQARgH+Wnp6PAALHjAp6xnkAHc4KE0AVXN+BgHzTbh9Q31kACNNyOAnAdEAGhWZzThQfYGAIQgQBDnUqA8bADB6DACSv30oAgEWQ31+-2aQJBgyGEAM0LhPz+TUB2GBj2e9FwdRA+QoHyG2k0FwuEFOyAAYvpCiiBgQLoZkHhTPiSAA3aBMlnA0EDFLogC0UQQAGtheR7k9VgplTNPsAkE5lqt6AAZEj6OAfT6bOkMvDaKD6NlpCCIBZQblWm2E3WXEgXEgfAASWU0Qst1tFgw5XKDNrFVJp5vOEaVz1V1iT9GGowATJN+vQAMpzMz6KJQZzTXV1bDexiHY6nemXa4RW4EtWrOoAR20EBN2P+dvxbIhGJAMKxCNxyKj6Khw9HOKR-bduuw5PIlOptPp52ZrLFYZQPJIfMFTu3IfFUpl8u3CZVLeQAEELiWiWU3iAPjztAi2XqOMhMqwzaJmqKaoqMADMWalvQppyjquobFsuwfEcmS1ucVxOo2dyLqsrzvFW8I4n2Z6DtOI5EYieJnmiQ4oJR44LnexLovUK5rjGm4Kmee7cryFbHtxtoXuiV4sjeMygfQAAqXBas+7r4e+hFmlx8ZinaDqBi6EmrCSbGbKuVZ+poAZOhGPFwJy+46VG66xs61q6cgoFJgo8jKDQpKNPkhS9MgADyFwAFbomAAB0PyuDwAAUzSdK0ACU8gAPQpbkxQiKC5T2FU5iiDIyi+dgDAAAwFeV-kAOQAHIQGskSjCAWQQFVtT1I0w5rB0XRtACCXdH0QWhQgEUwKYmgAKLgFwsXFYlyhAA)

Comment: Yes, I just changed days type to be Array<[string, muscleGroup]> and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

in some most cases you can remove types and let TypeScript to infer them. In your case you can remove type of `days` - `Array<[string, object]>`. TS will infer them from `program` and `Object.entries` type declarations.

```js
const days = Object.entries(program);

days[0][0] = 'New day name'

const newProgram:Program = Object.fromEntries(days)
```

Here you've got working code in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAggD2g4BnCBhOSAcwHsoBPZAbwChlkBtdTHfQiUqYCbALmWxguIIgF1%20g4UQaiA3DQC%20NGqEixEKALYBXbAgA2EAOJQS2gA7U6jHXsMmz5vgKGgx-ZlCy4CxMuXklGnRzMjBkABMIeG19cNVoeCRkAAVTIig4TSt6Bgi4cmdJN3FkWwNjUwtA5QQSEEFkc3TMzX40kgys5ABeHOQAIgARAuQARgH%20Wnp6PAALHjAp6xnkAHc4KE0AVXN%20BgHzTbh9Q31kACNNyOAnAdEAGhWZzThQfYGAIQgQBDnUqA8bADB6DACSv30oAgEWQ31%20-2aQJBgyGEAM0LhPz%20TUB2GBj2e9FwdRA%20QoHyG2k0FwuEFOyAAYvpCiiBgQLoZkHhTPiSAA3aBMlnA0EDFLogC0UQQAGtheR7k9VgplTNPsAkE5lqt6AAZEj6OAfT6bOkMvDaKD6NlpCCIBZQblWm2E3WXEgXEgfAASWU0Qst1tFgw5XKDNrFVJp5vOEaVz1V1iT9GGowATJN%20vQAMpzMz6KJQZzTXV1bDexiHY6nemXa4RW4EtWrOoAR20EBN2P%20dvxbIhGJAMKxCNxyKj6Khw9HOKR-bduuw5PIlOptPp52ZrLFYZQPJIfMFTu3IfFUpl8u3CZVLeQAEELiWiWU3iAPjztAi2XqOMhMqwzaJmqKaoqMADMWalvQppyjquobFsuwfEcmS1ucVxOo2dyLqsrzvFW8I4n2Z6DtOI5EYieJnmiQ4oJR44LnexLovUK5rjGm4Kmee7cryFbHtxtoXuiV4sjeMygfQAAqXBas%207r4e%20hFmlx8ZinaDqBi6EmrCSbGbKuVZ%20poAZOhGPFwJy%2046VG66xs61q6cgoFJgo8jKDQpKNPkhS9MgADyFwAFbomAAB0PyuDwAAUzSdK0ACUHm%20dgDAAAyiBloj%20QA5AAchAayRKMIBZBAuW1PUjTDmsHRdG09WtP5QWhQgEUwKYmgAKLgFwsWpYlQA)